# Lifetime woes when using threads

Tags: closures, rust, lifetime

I'm having a hard time getting this to compile:

```
use std::thread::{self, JoinHandle};

struct Foo<'c> {
    foo: &'c str,
}

impl<'c> Foo<'c> {
    fn use_in_another_thread<F>(self, mut cb: F) -> JoinHandle<Foo<'c>>
        where F: FnOnce(&mut Foo),
              F: Send
    {
        thread::spawn(move || {
            cb(&mut self);
            self
        })
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

As far as I can see the lifetimes are sound, but I'm getting errors...

```
error[E0477]: the type `[closure@src/main.rs:12:23: 15:10 cb:F, self:Foo<'c>]` does not fulfill the required lifetime
  --> src/main.rs:12:9
   |
12 |         thread::spawn(move || {
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |
   = note: type must outlive the static lifetime

error[E0495]: cannot infer an appropriate lifetime due to conflicting requirements
  --> src/main.rs:14:13
   |
14 |             self
   |             ^^^^
   |
note: first, the lifetime cannot outlive the lifetime 'c as defined on the body at 11:4...
  --> src/main.rs:11:5
   |
11 |       {
   |  _____^ starting here...
12 | |         thread::spawn(move || {
13 | |             cb(&mut self);
14 | |             self
15 | |         })
16 | |     }
   | |_____^ ...ending here
note: ...so that expression is assignable (expected std::thread::JoinHandle<Foo<'c>>, found std::thread::JoinHandle<Foo<'_>>)
  --> src/main.rs:12:9
   |
12 |           thread::spawn(move || {
   |  _________^ starting here...
13 | |             cb(&mut self);
14 | |             self
15 | |         })
   | |__________^ ...ending here
   = note: but, the lifetime must be valid for the static lifetime...
note: ...so that the type `Foo<'_>` will meet its required lifetime bounds
  --> src/main.rs:12:9
   |
12 |         thread::spawn(move || {
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I don't understand what lifetimes the errors are referring to - the lifetime of the closure body? - or why they must outlive the static lifetime.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The lifetime constraint that is causing this problem is the one in `Thread::spawn`, which requires the `FnOnce` closure to be `Send`. `Send` requires `'static`, which means that the data contains no non-`'static` data. Your data, `Foo`, contains a borrowed `str`, which is not `'static`, which makes `Foo` non-`'static`. As a result, you can't send `Foo` across threads.

Why is this? Since `Foo` contains a borrow, it is valid for only a small lifetime. If Rust allowed you to send an instance of `Foo` to another thread, then that thread could easily use `Foo` long after the data it borrows has become invalid.

You might think that this is actually overly restrictive, and you'd be right. There's no reason to not allow *local* parallelism as long as you can prove to the borrow checker that the thread terminates within some lifetime. There are currently no constructs in Rust to do this, but there are some future solutions for this problem, such as [this RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/458) which extends the `Send` trait to allow local parallelism.