# What should the type signature be for a function that takes a function and returns another function that returns a handle to a thread?

Tags: parallel-processing, rust

I'm trying to write a function `parallelize` that takes as an argument a function `B` and returns a function `C`, where `C` returns a handle to a thread which is running `B`. I understand this may be clunky or ridiculous; it's mostly as a learning project. The higher level goal is to implement a parallel map function on iterators, where each element of the list will be mapped in a different thread (or potentially through a thread pool eventually). I have quickly realized that I'm in way over my head. Given what I have described, what should the type of `parallelize` be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Let's step through it piece by piece:

> a function `parallelize`

```
fn parallelize() {
    unimplemented!()
}
```

Yes, that's a function alright.

> argument a function B

I assume you'd like the function to be able to return something, so I'll use the generic type `R`.

```
fn parallelize<B, R>(function: B)
where
    B: FnOnce() -> R,
{
    unimplemented!()
}
```

> returns a function C

Uh oh. You [can't do this cleanly in Rust yet](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25445761/155423). That means we will return a *boxed trait object* instead

```
fn parallelize<B, R>(function: B) -> Box<FnOnce()>
where
    B: FnOnce() -> R,
{
    unimplemented!()
}
```

> where C returns a handle to a thread which is running B

```
use std::thread::JoinHandle;

fn parallelize<B, R>(function: B) -> Box<FnOnce() -> JoinHandle<R>>
where
    B: FnOnce() -> R,
{
    unimplemented!()
}
```

And there's your signature. All done here!

.....

Of course, there's more to do. For example, you didn't state when the thread should actually *start*. That means I get to pick, and I pick the easiest way — the thread is started when the caller asks for the handle.

```
use std::thread::{self, JoinHandle};

fn parallelize<B, R>(function: B) -> Box<FnOnce() -> JoinHandle<R>>
where
    B: Send + FnOnce() -> R + 'static,
    R: Send + 'static,
{
    Box::new(|| thread::spawn(function))
}
```

I guess you could start it immediately, as well:

```
use std::thread::{self, JoinHandle};

fn parallelize<B, R>(function: B) -> Box<FnOnce() -> JoinHandle<R>>
where
    B: Send + FnOnce() -> R + 'static,
    R: Send + 'static,
{
    let handle = thread::spawn(function);
    Box::new(|| handle)
}
```

I don't know *why* you'd do the second one; in that case you might as well just return the handle directly. And if you do **that**, you might as well just call `thread::spawn` directly.

Oh, I suppose I couldn't slip those extra trait bounds past you, could I? When calling `thread::spawn`, you have to ensure that nothing you pass it will stop being valid before the thread exits (thus `'static`) and is safe to transfer between threads (thus `Send`).

> The higher level goal is to implement a parallel map function on iterators

That exists and is called [Rayon](https://crates.io/crates/rayon).

---

See also:

- [How can I pass a reference to a stack variable to a thread?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32750829/155423)
- [Lifetime of variables passed to a new thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34439977/155423)
- [How do I use static lifetimes with threads?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30562443/155423)
- [Cannot call a function in a spawned thread because it "does not fulfill the required lifetime"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33938547/155423)
- [Lifetime woes when using threads](https://stackoverflow.com/q/27754877/155423)
- [Thread references require static lifetime?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32981382/155423)
- ["the type does not fulfill the required lifetime" when using a method in a thread](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33442053/155423)